# Хочу создать туннель для нормальной работы с ms exchange

Tags: linux, iptables, archlinux, exchange, tunnel

Дано: система на arch linux + Gnome + gnome-online-accounts

Проблема: google-online-accounts с недавних пор поддерживает учетки MS Exchange, вот только не совсем корректно. http-proxy оно еще не умеет, поэтому добавив свою учетку, я вижу вот такое сообщение "Ошибка разрешения 'examplemail01.example.local': Имя или служба неизвестны.

Поэтому я хочу (с вашей помощью) создать подключение к удаленному прокси и направить в него весь трафик, который касается домена example.local. и/или local.

Подозреваю понадобится что-то вроде httptunnel и iptables как минимум, но точный набор команд / настроек я самостоятельно не подберу.

Comment: iptables можно прозрачно заворачивать весь трафик 80 порта правилом redirect на проксик. conntrack позволит трафику ходить туда-сюда и все будет ОК.

Comment: А мне весь трафик заворачивать не нужно, у меня помимо exchange есть еще и другие учетки, которые через прокси ходить не должны.